# How can I do an electoral semicircle within another to compare several years with plotly or ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly

I'm trying to do a electoral semicircle with plotly or ggplot and I don't know how because there are only options like circles or completly donuts. Also, I need to put one inside another to compare elections from differents years, something like this
electoral semicircle:

[image: electoral semicircle]

Comment: Welcome to SO! Could you share some data (also fake data) and your attempts?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution with `coord_polar()`:

```
# Some fake data
df <- data.frame(
  x = rep(1:2, eadch = 50),
  cat = sample(LETTERS[1:3], 100, replace = T)
)

# Plotting code
ggplot(df, aes(x, fill = cat)) +
  geom_bar(position = "stack") +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 100)) +
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(-1, 3)) +
  coord_polar(start = -pi/2, direction = 1,
              theta = "y")
```

[image]

And here is a solution using ggforce's `geom_arc_bar()`:

```
# Re-parameterise the data
df2 <- as.data.frame(table(df$cat, df$x))
df2$start <- c(cumsum(c(0, df2$Freq[1:2]) / sum(df2$Freq[1:3])),
               cumsum(c(0, df2$Freq[4:5]) / sum(df2$Freq[4:6])))
df2$end <- c(cumsum(df2$Freq[1:3]) / sum(df2$Freq[1:3]), 
             cumsum(df2$Freq[4:6]) / sum(df2$Freq[4:6]))
df2$Var2 <- as.numeric(df2$Var2)

# Plot
ggplot(df2) +
  geom_arc_bar(aes(x0 = 0, y0 = 0, fill = Var1,
                   r0 = Var2, r = Var2 + 0.9,
                   start = start / 1* pi - 0.5 * pi, 
                   end = end / 1 * pi - 0.5 * pi)) +
  theme(aspect.ratio = 0.5)
```

[image]

And that should be it to get you started. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you! I will try it. But I would like to do it preferably with plotly to make an interactive plot